# Not able to import a class from a another package in python

Tags: python, class, package, class-hierarchy

```
* myproject
   + getdir
       - somename.py
   + pushdir
       - nicename.py
```

I'm trying to import a class from somename.py into nicename.py.
At first I created the the  `__init__.py`  file and left it empty.
Then I wrote (in nicename.py):

```
from ..getdir.somename import classnameexample
```

and I also tried the command without double points at first.

It returns:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'getdir'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant but you can add the path in `sys.path` before importing `getdir`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from getdir import somename #Now python will look for getdir in sys.path, including at '../'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. Now im getting the following error message: **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

Comment: when I do `from getdir import somename` it returns:*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Objects* and when I do `from ..getdir import somename`it returns:**ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

Comment: Is this Object module imported in somename ? where is it ?

Comment: I'm sorry. "Object" is my real folder name. In our example it shall show: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named getdir**

Comment: hm. Do you run nicename.py from the pushdir directory ? I did replicate your example and it works on my side

Comment: if you run it from ```myproject```, then you should replace ```sys.path.append('..')``` by ```sys.path.append('.')```

Comment: im going to try it

Answer (score 0):

Could you try (works for me):

from getdir.somename import classnameexample

Comment: I'm sorry for telling that. But you maybe didn't get the question.

Comment: No problem, seems to be so